# new raspbian image doesn't detect usb cdc device

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, usb, kernel, raspbian-buster

I have a usb cdc device that works fine in raspbian stretch. But when I change the image to new raspbian buster, my usb device isn't recognized.

lsusb doesn't list my device at all! I've enabled cdc-acm module by:

```
sudo modprobe cdc-acm
```

but this doesn't solve the problem.

Any idea that what is the problem? and what can I do to make my usb device work with latest raspbian image?

---

EDIT :‌

My device

> VID=0x03eb

and

> PID=0x2018

Here is the dmesg message :

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.19.57-v7+ (dom@buildbot) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611)) #1244 SMP Thu Jul 4 18:45:25 BST 2019
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fd034] revision 4 (ARMv7), cr=10c5383d
[    0.000000] CPU: div instructions available: patching division code
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 8 MiB at 0x3ac00000
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 242688
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 2133 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 242688 pages, LIFO batch:63
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0xac/0x4b4 with crng_init=0
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 17 pages/cpu s39488 r8192 d21952 u69632
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s39488 r8192 d21952 u69632 alloc=17*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 240555
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=0 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1824 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=984 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=346c8cc1-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 939088K/970752K available (8192K kernel code, 629K rwdata, 2176K rodata, 1024K init, 821K bss, 23472K reserved, 8192K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
                   vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
                   fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
                   vmalloc : 0xbb800000 - 0xff800000   (1088 MB)
                   lowmem  : 0x80000000 - 0xbb400000   ( 948 MB)
                   modules : 0x7f000000 - 0x80000000   (  16 MB)
                     .text : 0x(ptrval) - 0x(ptrval)   (9184 kB)
                     .init : 0x(ptrval) - 0x(ptrval)   (1024 kB)
                     .data : 0x(ptrval) - 0x(ptrval)   ( 630 kB)
                      .bss : 0x(ptrval) - 0x(ptrval)   ( 822 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 26351 entries in 78 pages
[    0.000000] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 19.20MHz (phys).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x46d987e47, max_idle_ns: 440795202767 ns
[    0.000007] sched_clock: 56 bits at 19MHz, resolution 52ns, wraps every 4398046511078ns
[    0.000018] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 52ns
[    0.000275] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000295] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.000336] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 38.40 BogoMIPS (lpj=192000)
[    0.000353] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.000693] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000708] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.001618] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.002080] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
[    0.002735] Setting up static identity map for 0x100000 - 0x10003c
[    0.002886] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.003691] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.004531] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
[    0.005460] CPU2: thread -1, cpu 2, socket 0, mpidr 80000002
[    0.006324] CPU3: thread -1, cpu 3, socket 0, mpidr 80000003
[    0.006447] smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
[    0.006458] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated (153.60 BogoMIPS).
[    0.006464] CPU: All CPU(s) started in HYP mode.
[    0.006469] CPU: Virtualization extensions available.
[    0.007443] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.020586] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 40 variant 3 rev 4
[    0.020827] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.020846] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.021431] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.022296] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.025349] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.031123] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.031131] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.031332] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.033612] bcm2835-mbox 3f00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.068836] bcm2835-dma 3f007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager at (ptrval), dmachans=0x1
[    0.070519] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.070747] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.070809] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.070903] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.090129] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2019-07-09 14:40, variant start
[    0.100388] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Firmware hash is 6c3fe3f096a93de3b34252ad98cdccadeb534be2
[    0.111849] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.200593] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.200676] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.200868] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.201076] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.211089] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.211906] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 6144 bytes)
[    0.211944] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.212055] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.212241] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.212375] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.212421] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.212733] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.213308] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.213314] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.213320] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.213326] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.215061] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a7 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    0.218025] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    0.218219] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=18 bucket_order=4
[    0.228007] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    0.228573] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.228599] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.228606] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.228622] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    0.230886] Key type asymmetric registered
[    0.230896] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    0.230950] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 250)
[    0.231107] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.231115] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    0.231296] io scheduler cfq registered
[    0.231304] io scheduler mq-deadline registered (default)
[    0.231311] io scheduler kyber registered
[    0.234570] bcm2708_fb soc:fb: FB found 1 display(s)
[    0.285199] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 228x61
[    0.313708] bcm2708_fb soc:fb: Registered framebuffer for display 0, size 1824x984
[    0.315901] bcm2835-rng 3f104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    0.316212] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3ec00000 mem_size:0x40000000(1024 MiB)
[    0.316742] vc-sm: Videocore shared memory driver
[    0.317059] gpiomem-bcm2835 3f200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0x3f200000
[    0.328007] brd: module loaded
[    0.338450] loop: module loaded
[    0.339096] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    0.339845] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    0.339950] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    0.340015] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    0.340032] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    0.367892] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: base=(ptrval)
[    0.568152] Core Release: 2.80a
[    0.568162] Setting default values for core params
[    0.568196] Finished setting default values for core params
[    0.768495] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    0.768503] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    0.768509] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    0.768517] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    0.768536] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    0.769022] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1045: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = bad04000 dma = 0xfad04000 len=9024
[    0.769049] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
               Non-periodic Split Transactions
               Periodic Split Transactions
               High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
               Interrupt/Control Split Transaction hack enabled
[    0.769057] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    0.769115] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:457: FIQ on core 1
[    0.769127] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:458: FIQ ASM at 80650d3c length 36
[    0.769139] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:497: MPHI regs_base at bb810000
[    0.769156] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    0.769191] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.769227] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: irq 56, io mem 0x00000000
[    0.769277] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    0.769283] Init: Power Port (0)
[    0.769542] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 4.19
[    0.769553] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.769563] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    0.769572] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.19.57-v7+ dwc_otg_hcd
[    0.769581] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 3f980000.usb
[    0.770229] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.770275] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    0.770880] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    0.770888] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    0.770893] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    0.770906] Module dwc_common_port init
[    0.771192] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    0.771382] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    0.772318] bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    0.772557] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=600000 max=1200000
[    0.773030] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.773036] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    0.773423] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmcnr: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    0.773815] sdhost-bcm2835 3f202000.mmc: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    0.773942] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    0.775477] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    0.775678] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    0.775858] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    0.775863] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    0.776850] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = (ptrval), is_master = 0
[    0.778322] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    0.789026] [vc_sm_connected_init]: end - returning 0
[    0.790168] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    0.790192] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    0.790303] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    0.790891] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    0.791554] registered taskstats version 1
[    0.791572] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    0.798836] uart-pl011 3f201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
[    0.798925] 3f201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 81, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    0.800835] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmcnr: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    0.800845] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmcnr: DMA channel allocated
[    0.825233] sdhost: log_buf @ (ptrval) (fad07000)
[    0.863829] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
[    0.865392] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    0.866951] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    0.869756] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
[    0.871881] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[    0.873243] of_cfs_init
[    0.873343] of_cfs_init: OK
[    0.873985] Waiting for root device PARTUUID=346c8cc1-02...
[    0.942629] random: fast init done
[    0.963527] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    0.967273] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
[    0.968660] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SL32G 29.7 GiB
[    0.972075]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    0.982039] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[    1.007648] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    1.007659] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    1.046065] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    1.191896] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[    1.192050] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[    1.432169] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514, bcdDevice= 2.00
[    1.432183] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.432897] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.433008] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
[    1.751930] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    1.882237] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00, bcdDevice= 2.00
[    1.882255] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.885140] smsc95xx v1.0.6
[    1.918169] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
[    1.927289] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): 2 orphan inodes deleted
[    1.927298] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): recovery complete
[    1.939967] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    1.940036] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
[    1.940857] devtmpfs: mounted
[    1.947344] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1024K
[    1.962230] Run /sbin/init as init process
[    1.975768] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:11:96:2f
[    2.071925] usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    2.221173] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1c4f, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 1.10
[    2.221189] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.221199] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB Keykoard
[    2.221208] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: SIGMACH1P
[    2.231624] input: SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:1C4F:0002.0001/input/input0
[    2.292565] hid-generic 0003:1C4F:0002.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.3/input0
[    2.301944] input: SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard Consumer Control as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1/0003:1C4F:0002.0002/input/input1
[    2.372178] input: SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard System Control as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1/0003:1C4F:0002.0002/input/input2
[    2.372436] hid-generic 0003:1C4F:0002.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.3/input1
[    2.528051] systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
[    2.657170] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.658727] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    2.708712] systemd[1]: systemd 241 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    2.709646] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm.
[    2.718112] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <raspberrypi>.
[    2.729772] systemd[1]: Failed to bump fs.file-max, ignoring: Invalid argument
[    3.089311] systemd[1]: File /lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service:12 configures an IP firewall (IPAddressDeny=any), but the local system does not support BPF/cgroup based firewalling.
[    3.089338] systemd[1]: Proceeding WITHOUT firewalling in effect! (This warning is only shown for the first loaded unit using IP firewalling.)
[    3.621810] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.633916] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.634659] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    3.635233] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.635542] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    3.636002] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    3.641460] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[    3.839754] i2c /dev entries driver
[    3.862640] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[    3.862653] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[    4.456296] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    4.571404] systemd-journald[103]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    5.291630] vc_sm_cma: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    5.294983] bcm2835_vc_sm_cma_probe: Videocore shared memory driver
[    5.295000] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    5.300158] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    5.303757] [vc_sm_connected_init]: installed successfully
[    5.348233] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    5.395735] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    5.395756] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    5.413588] bcm2835_v4l2: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    5.435833] snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    5.439142] bcm2835_codec: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    5.443662] bcm2835_audio soc:audio: card created with 8 channels
[    5.482488] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video10
[    5.482511] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 decode
[    5.490211] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video11
[    5.490237] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 encode
[    5.522800] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video12
[    5.522816] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 isp
[    5.869132] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    6.049764] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    6.319944] brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x1541a9a6
[    6.342342] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
[    6.342627] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    6.567784] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
[    6.567912] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_process_clm_blob: no clm_blob available (err=-2), device may have limited channels available
[    6.568750] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43430/1 wl0: Oct 23 2017 03:55:53 version 7.45.98.38 (r674442 CY) FWID 01-e58d219f
[    6.896257] random: crng init done
[    6.896272] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[    8.252461] input: BRLTTY 5.4 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard as /devices/virtual/input/input3
[   13.339442] uart-pl011 3f201000.serial: no DMA platform data
[   13.428632] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[   13.740554] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS
[   13.909146] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   13.909174] brcmfmac: power management disabled
[   14.414493] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[   14.415171] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   16.074150] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1
[   16.076283] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   18.154367] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   18.154468] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   18.154475] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   18.154500] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   18.154513] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   18.154556] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   18.174797] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   18.174826] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   18.175093] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   18.176520] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   19.155708] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   19.155722] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   19.155739] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   19.227770] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   19.227800] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   19.227819] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   19.527245] fuse init (API version 7.27)
[   29.081917] usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[   29.213303] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5567, bcdDevice= 1.00
[   29.213320] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   29.213330] usb 1-1.5: Product: Cruzer Blade
[   29.213339] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[   29.213364] usb 1-1.5: SerialNumber: 4C530001111226117055
[   29.214318] usb-storage 1-1.5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   29.214957] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.5:1.0
[   29.292196] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[   30.233335] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Blade     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[   30.234773] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 15232000 512-byte logical blocks: (7.80 GB/7.26 GiB)
[   30.236199] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[   30.236217] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[   30.236696] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   30.246397]  sda: sda1
[   30.249679] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   30.265741] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[   30.889353] FAT-fs (sda1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[   42.952075] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
[   43.691683] input: BRLTTY 5.4 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard as /devices/virtual/input/input4
[   47.111901] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
[   79.183930] input: BRLTTY 5.4 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard as /devices/virtual/input/input5
[  111.772193] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[  111.907173] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c534, bcdDevice=29.01
[  111.907190] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  111.907200] usb 1-1.4: Product: USB Receiver
[  111.907209] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Logitech
[  111.921296] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:046D:C534.0003/input/input6
[  111.983727] hid-generic 0003:046D:C534.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.4/input0
[  111.991743] input: Logitech USB Receiver Mouse as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0004/input/input7
[  111.993065] input: Logitech USB Receiver Consumer Control as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0004/input/input8
[  112.064157] input: Logitech USB Receiver System Control as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0004/input/input9
[  112.068583] hid-generic 0003:046D:C534.0004: input,hiddev96,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.4/input1
[  114.683096] input: BRLTTY 5.4 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard as /devices/virtual/input/input12
[  150.187582] input: BRLTTY 5.4 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard as /devices/virtual/input/input13
[  151.112661] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
[  155.272623] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
```

Comment: I found some devices that works on Rpi3B+ USB2 no longer works on Rpi4B USB3. But then I found Rpi4B USB2 still works. I guess it is the USB3 driver problem.  Have you tried both Rpi4B USB2 and USB3 sockets?

Comment: @tlfong01 : Actually I'm using Rpi3B and B+ and the problem occurres in both models. But I don't have a Rpi4 to test. How can I resolve the usb3 or usb2 driver problem?

Comment: Hi @payman, Ah sorry, I wrongly thought that you upgraded to Rpi4B at the same time.  Anyway, my comment applies to OS upgrade as well. In other words, when you upgrade from stretch to buster, the drivers in buster might not be able to detect the devices that are used to be detected by preinstalled drivers in buster. Or there are no longer any drivers for the device.  Or the driver you use /boot/config.txt to config needs to be updated or recompiled.

Comment: Hi @tlfong01 , My device is a generic usb cdc device and doesn't require any custom driver. in previous raspbian it was enough to enable cdc-acm kernel module. What else must be done in new image?

Comment: this device is my own design. It is an atmel avr based device. in jessie and wheezy this device works fine. but in buster it is not recognized.

Comment: First, fix the tag: if you have an RPi3, you should tag the question `pi-3`, not `pi-2`. Could you share your `dmesg` log collected during device plug-in?

Comment: @tlfong01 USB-CDC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications_device_class USB CDC ACM:   https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/acm.txt **Please refrain from hijacking threads with random unrelated tangents.**

Comment: Unplug your device, then re-insert it. What results do you get from a `dmesg` command (which shows kernel messages)? What do you get from a `lsusb` command? Can you edit your question and add those two pieces?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev  I've edited the quenstion and added dmesg message.

Comment: @payman I can't find the vendor ID you have posted in your `dmesg` log. Could you perhaps post just the lines which appear as you plug the device in? Or state that no new lines appear in the log?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev This is the problem that makes me to ask this question! My device is not detected at all. So it is not appear in demsg logs. Also lsusb doesn't list my device.

Comment: This is indeed strange. Nothing in `dmesg` usually means an electrical problem, yet you say that your device works if you run Stretch instead of Buster on the same hardware. If you can reproduce the issue with a generally available device (e.g. Arduino Micro), you should file a bug to Raspbian bug tracker.